# Angular translate and pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-translate

Using the translate on a ng-repeat. I am also using pagination (angular-ui). The issue is that the translations are not updated once the page changes.

Here is a quick demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5rbqMetHalqs8EEXRKur?p=preview

```
no code to show, but putting this here to please SO
```

So change the page and you'll notice the translations stay the same and are incorrect against the letters, except on the first page.

Can I re-bind them somehow?
Thank you
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but if you remove the "track by $index", It seems to work

Comment: Oh yeah. Wonder what that is about. I'll mention it on the ticket over at https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/759